# PHP closing mysqli connection to database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

The case in which I'm getting this error is diffrent from what I have seen on SO, in trying to solve my problem. I have a class, Database, which creates only one instance of itself, trying to limit the number of connection to mysql server to one. Here is my class **[code 1]**:

```
class Database {

    private $_connection;

    // Store the single instance.
    private static $_instance;

    /**
     * Get self instance of database to private static variable $_instance.
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $database
     * @return Database
     */
      public static function getInstance($host,$username,$password,$database) {
          if (!self::$_instance) {
              self::$_instance = new self($host,$username,$password,$database);
          }
          return self::$_instance;
      }

      /**
       * Constructor.
       * @param string $host
       * @param string $username
       * @param string $password
       * @param string $database
       */
       public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$database) {
           $this->_connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

        // Error handling.
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Empty clone magic method to prevent duplication.
    */
     private function __clone() {}

     /**
     * Get the mysqli connection;
     */ 
      public function getConnection(){
          return $this->_connection;
      }
  }
```

After this class, I created a connection for getting some info from a table. The code is the following **[code 2]**:

```
    // Establish a connection with MySQL Server database.
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'barbu';
    $password = 'watcrn0y';
    $database = 'siteinfo';

    $db = Database::getInstance($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

    // Get the firstname of the author of the site from database.
    $sql_query = 'SELECT author.firstname, author.lastname ';
    $sql_query .= 'FROM author;';

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);


    if($result && $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $author_firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $author_lastname = $row['lastname'];
    }
```

Now, in another file, I do this **[code 3]**:

```
require '../includes/siteinfo.php'; // this file contains the connection 
    // with first database ['siteinfo']. 
    //I include this file for accessing some other variables from it, which aren't  
   //in the code posted above. 

// Establish the connection to server.
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'barbu';
$password = 'watcrn0y';
$database = 'articles';

// Here I need to close my previous connection and begin another.
// It is important to remember that my class is designed for creating 
// just one connection at a time.
// So if I want to change the connection to another database, 
// I have to close the previous one and create the one which 
// suits my needs.
$mysqli->close();
unset($db);

$db = Database::getInstance($host, $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli = $db->getConnection();



// Send the post info to the server.
$title = (isset($_POST['title'])) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
$text = (isset($_POST['text'])) ? $_POST['text'] : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO postInfo ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('" . $author_firstname . " " . $author_lastname ."', '" . 
date('d D M Y') . "', '" . $title . "', '" . $text . "');";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

While doing this, I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/barbu/blog/admin/index.php on line 24

If I don't close the first connection (and let say I let just ['unset($db)']), my query will be executed on the first database ['siteinfo'], and I'm getting another error message, namely one telling me that the 'postInfo' table doesn't exist in 'siteinfo' database, which is true. If I let that connection to persist, and declare another instance of Database class, $db1, and another mysqli object, $mysqli1, which hold my connection, and execute my query through it, I get the same mysqli error message as in second case: 'siteinfo.postInfo' doesn't exist. What do you recommand me? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're writing your own ORM when there's several first-class ones out there? Using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) is highly recommended before you dig yourself too deep a hole here.

Comment: @tadman: I didn't heard about those two libraries. I even didn't know what ORM means. I'll take a look on those two and try familiarize with them. I think it will make it easier for me to handle at the begining databases. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's often the case people re-invent the wheel without knowing wheels exist, it's a logical path to follow. An ORM makes interfacing with your database easier and most give you ways of formalizing changes to your schema in a way that makes deploying these changes a lot easier to manage. Hope they help!

Comment: I will consider what you've said about SQL injection danger. I know that I didn't sanitized my code, firstly I just want to make it work like I want it.

Comment: Getting it working is a good first step, but don't forget that the way you have it here is very brittle. A single apostrophe is going to cause a catastrophic error. A hostile user could destroy your system if given a chance. Be careful!

Comment: Yes, you're right about the wheel! I try to keep it away, but also reinveing it helps you learn. It's not always an easy proccess.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Actually I myself will try to break it. I want to be the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to have only one connection per session and not allow to create a seccond instance you should define `Database::__construct` as private. 
Then add a new method `Database::close`. The idea of this method is to close the connection and set the link to instance of class Database to null. The code will look like this:

```
public function close() 
{
   if (self::$_instance) {
       self::$_instance->getConnection()->close();
       self::$_instance = null;
   }
}
```

Final point, instead of `$mysqli->close();` you should call `$db->close();`

Comment: Well, that's the answer! Thank you very much, all works fine know! Also, why should I define Database::__construct private in order to get that behaviour for my class? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Because it's possible to create a new instance like $db = new Database(); and you want to avoid it. @lulian

Comment: Oh, I see. When you create a new instance of an object, construct magic method is called, so defining it as private will not let the method execute.